# Database normalization for multiple user 'types'

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I wanted some guidance on structuring the database for my biggest application to date. It's the first app I've created with multiple user types.

I have two types of users - A coach which has many clients, and a client which potentially has many coaches, but currently lets say they only have one.

Both coach and client share certain things -

```
users (shared info)
column name      | data type | details
-----------------|-----------|-----------------------
id               | integer   | not null, primary key
username         | string    | not null
email            | string    | not null
password_digest  | string    | not null
session_token    | string    | not null
```

My first thought is to have two other tables, one listing type, and the next joining type and users.

```
type
column name      | data type | details
-----------------|-----------|-----------------------
id               | integer   | not null, primary key
coach            | string    |
client           | string    |
```

User type

```
user_type
column name      | data type | details
-----------------|-----------|-----------------------
id               | integer   | not null, primary key
user_id          | integer   | not null, foreign key (users)
type_id          | integer   | not null, foreign key (type)
```

My question is, where would it be best to store the user_ids associated with a coach.

A coach has many clients. Would I need another table, or would this be best as a column in something already existing such as user_type?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I would recommend keeping it simple.  Over time, models like Coach and Client are surely to change and have different implementation requirements.  The pattern thats been suggested (having a single Users model and table) will only lead to tight coupling down the road.  If behavior is indeed shared between the two models down the road, that is an excellent use case for Mixin's (Modules) or using ActiveModel::Concern.

You should have a separate Coach and Client model and database table.  You said you need to setup a has_one or has_many relationship, so you already need a coach_id field that is unique to Clients.  I would recommend building the `has_many` from the start since its very easy to setup now, but its more difficult to migrate from a `has_one` to `has_many` relationship later IMHO.

I'd personally stick with this and refactor over time.

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord #or ActiveRecord::Base if Rails 4 or lower
  belongs_to :coach
end

class Coach < ApplicationRecord #or ActiveRecord::Base if Rails 4 or lower
  has_many :clients
end
```

Comment: Yea this makes sense, so essentially a coach and client would have separate tables, they'd both be users, and then I'd create a join table for clients and coaches.

Comment: No.  Two separate tables.  No join table.  The Client table would have a `coach_id` column on it.